# Setting global array from inside readFile

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

I'm probably missing something simple here, but for some reason, when I set an array's value from inside a function, I can no longer read that array once outside of that function.

```
    var threadArray = []; 

    function getThreads() {
      var fs = require('fs');        
      // read list of threads
      fs.readFile('./database/threadList.txt', function(err, data) { 
        var threadIds = data.toString().split("\n");    
        for(i in threadIds) { threadArray[i] = threadIds[i].split(","); } 
        console.log("This works: " + threadArray[0])
      }) 
      console.log("This does not work: " + threadArray[0] + " Returns [undefined]")
    }
```

What am I missing here? I'm assuming something to do with the way I declared the array?

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous. Use `fs.readFileSync` instead

Comment: @ajaiJothi Bingo! Embarrassed I didn't notice that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a timing issue. `fs.readFile` is an asynchronous operation - your second console.log that doesn't work is getting processed immediately after `fs.readFile` starts running and your `threadArray` is not yet populated. You can use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options) instead

```
try {
  var threads = fs.readFileSync('./database/threadList.txt');
  var threadIds = threads.toString().split('\n');
  for(i in threadIds) { 
     threadArray[i] = threadIds[i].split(","); 
  } 
  console.log("This works: " + threadArray[0]);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error reading file: ", e);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I did that; you're absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I was able to help :-)